# ¿Es posible dibujar rectangulos en un pdf a través de un elemento AxAcroPdf?

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, pdf

Necesito dibujar rectángulos o líneas en un pdf utilizando como interfaz visual un controlador AxAcroPdf.

He intentado tomar los eventos del mouse de un elemento AxAcroPdf y al parecer eso no es posible, también intenté utilizar un PictureBox transparente encima del elemento AxAcroPdf para obtener los eventos del Mouse a través de este elemento y así poder traspasar las coordenadas del formulario a coordenadas dentro del Pdf, pero el PictureBox no es realmente transparente, en realidad toma el color de fondo por defecto de un elemento, asi que sigue tapando todo el elemento AxAcroPdf.

Quizás hay alguna otra forma de dibujar rectángulos en un pdf o una forma de hacer transparente el PictureBox y así poder emular un dibujo encima de un pdf. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

No se si podrá serte útil, pero yo para operaciones parecidas (pintar un rectángulo en pantalla con el ratón) y trasladarlo luego al PDF como un objeto recuadro de firma digital en el tamaño y coordenadas seleccionadas, lo efectué hace tiempo mediante la carga de una página del PDF en un picturebox (a través del ojeto PDDOC). Despúes, con las coordenadas del mouse (en pantalla y las relativas al picurebox cliente) y sus eventos generaba un rectángulo que luego le pasaba al PDDOC para generarlo exactamente igual dentro del PDF.